# Merging multiple paths in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, cs6

I've got multiple paths which, together, create a single sprite in Illustrator. I'm trying to merge the paths in order to apply a gradient to the whole thing; however, Pathfinder does nothing, and just joining the paths closes open paths and gives me unwanted, and very visible, jagged edges. Is there any other way to combine multiple paths to make them act as a single object, or apply a gradient to multiple paths as if they were a single object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using compound paths? Select all of your paths that you'd like to combine, and select `object -> compound path -> make`. Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> for windows) This will definitely allow you to apply the gradient across the entire set of paths.

Comment: Making compound path is like creating a multi-part from many single part path.

Answer (score -1):

Using Adobe Flash, you can break apart vectors and when ungrouped they automatically combine to form one vector. I still use Flash to this day because of simplicity such as this, and it still a great tool for quickly manipulating vectors.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  While Flash may help the OP please be advised he asked to do it in Illustrator.